# How to detect whether a asp.net script is already running?

Tags: asp.net

i want to create a script that would run forever. i mean i start the script today, and i should be able to see it running even in the next year.

this would not be possible because of the sever errors. it is obvious that the script will stop at least within 2 or 3 hours due to the server faults(im using a free web server).

so the method im going to use is to run two (or more) scripts simultaniously in two severs, and one scripts cheks if the other is runing & viceversa for every 30 seconds. and if found not running it executes the other one.
so the scripts will run as long as both of them are not stopped at once

1.my question is how do i check if the other asp.net script is running?
2.at least is there a way to check if another intance of the same asp.net script(in the same server) is already running?

Comment: When posting a question to SO, it's always helpful to include code you've already tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> i want to create a script that would run forever

ASP.NET is not the tool for this.  A web application is a request/response system.  It intercepts requests, performs a finite amount of processing, and returns a response.  At that point it's *done*.  Additionally, web servers are free to allocate and de-allocate resources for a number of reasons, so at any time your web application can be shut down.

What you're looking for is something more like a [Windows Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d56de412.aspx) or perhaps a [Console Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f492ca1w.aspx) (backed by a scheduler or something else to ensure that it's running).  Web applications by design don't "run forever" so they're not the right tool for the job.

Comment: thnx for ur quick reply, i too dont need it be an asp.net script neccesaraly. the reason i chose asp is that it is free, otherwise i will hav to go for something like vps and that would cost. and i canno kepp my pc on and keep it connected to internet 24 hours. the only way i found free was asp or php

Comment: @user2495720: Well, the right tool for the job isn't always free.  Web-hosted applications are cheaper to maintain, primarily *because* of the infrastructure which keeps them simple and allows them to have their resources re-allocated as needed.  This is why shared hosting is so cheap, they count on low resource utilization from most tenants.  Something that runs continuously doesn't fit into that model.

Answer (score 0):

ASP is not free but it is also not too expensive, we can run a script on server that can continuously work on server, but doing such thing on server can cause server load error, and will affect other websites which are hosted on shared hosting. You can go for VPS hosting, But I think that your server administrator can suspended your account on running such kind of script on server.